# Encoding of image

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, machine-learning, encoding

I have a problem with image encoding in opencv with python 3. As you see in code below I am trying to take a photo with camera in my computer and save it by `cv2.imwrite` but I am getting an error in next steps (second part of code). I want to upload my image to my CNN model. I was trying to load sample image and this works so I think the problem is with encoding of `cv2.imwrite` but I can't find solution in Google. I was trying to change `.jpg` to `.png` and using `with open(file, 'r'): etc` but it doesn't work. I think I need 'utf-16' but how to set this in my image? Thanks from the mountain.

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'): 
        crop_img = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w]
        check, frame = vc.read()
        cv2.imwrite(filename='C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/videosPython/Adam{}.jpg'.format(licznik), img=crop_img)
        img_new = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/videosPython/Adam{}.jpg'.format(licznik), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        print("Image Saved")
        licznik+=1
```

Output of code below: `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte`

```
test_image = image.load_img(img_new, target_size = (128, 128))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)

#predict the result
result = model_h1.predict(test_image)
print(result)
```

Traceback below

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-449745355f7b> in <module>
      3 img = 'C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/FaceID/augmented/augmented._0_545.jpg'
      4 
----> 5 test_image = image.load_img(img_new, target_size = (128, 128))
      6 test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
      7 test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)

~\anaconda3NEW\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\image.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    297       ValueError: if interpolation method is not supported.
    298   """
--> 299   return image.load_img(path, grayscale=grayscale, color_mode=color_mode,
    300                         target_size=target_size, interpolation=interpolation)
    301 

~\anaconda3NEW\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    111         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    112                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
--> 113     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    114         img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    115         if color_mode == 'grayscale':

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: First check if the image is saved successfully and you can watch it before to load it

Comment: Everything is ok about saving and opening files. I was testing it.

Comment: what is `image.load_img` and **what exact line** causes the error? you should always post the "Traceback". python gives you that.

Comment: Ok I have edited my post, now you can look at it

Comment: This error will happen if you open an image file in text-mode. from the error in line 5 in your earliest traceback snippet you have: `image.load_img(img_new, target_size = (128, 128)` - this `image_new` variable is probably an (incorrectly) open file, instead of just the patht o the file as defined in line 4 in the variable `img`
`img_new`

Comment: TL;DR: when making questions, please provide a complete code example that will actually trigger your error. In trying to post snippets you let the actual incorrect information missing. Your question would have been answered in seconds rather than in hours.

Comment: You are loading the image file two times, once using imread and the other with load_img, it makes no sense to pass pixel data to load_img, as it expects a file path, not pixel data.

Comment: Oh it works thank you soooo much man I love you. You are szef @jsbueno